# Does the SQL Server CE engine have to be told the commandtype is text if that should be obvious?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, compact-framework, .net-1.1

I've got this code:

```
using (SqlCeConnection sqlConn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=\my documents\\PlatypusDB.SDF"))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    string dmlStr = "insert into platypus_settings (setting_name, setting_value) values(?, ?)";
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(dmlStr, sqlConn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //<-- necessary?
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = settingName;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = settingVal;
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Platypus.ExceptionHandler(ex, "writeSettingsVal");
    }
}
```

...but don't know if the commented line is needed, is bloatcode, or doesn't matter either way?

Comment: Did you try running it both ways?

Comment: No, it's a long drawn-out process to do so (copying to the handheld device, etc.) I figured somebody knows. I would imagine it makes no real difference, but if it's not necessary, somebody probably knows that.

Comment: I just realized - that double slash in my connection string is probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... but don't know if the commented line is needed

No. Not because it's obvious but because it happens to be the default.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.commandtype%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Property Value
>   One of the CommandType values. The default is Text.

Having said that, it certainly is not bloat-code and I might include it, just to make the code a little less ambigious to read.